# How can two variables exchange value?

Tags: python

Is there any way for two variables to change values simpler/quicker than this one:

```
temp = var 1

var1 = temp

var2 = temp
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To swap variables. say `var1` and `var2`, use:

```
var2, var1 = var1, var2
```

#### Example

Let's define two variables:

```
>>> var1 = 1; var2 = 2
```

Now, let's swap them:

```
>>> var2, var1 = var1, var2
```

We can verify that they were successfully swapped:

```
>>> print('var1=', var1, 'var2=', var2)
var1= 2 var2= 1
```

Comment: I didn't know this was possible in Py.Thanks a ot John!

Answer (score 0):

That's likely to fail for floating point:

```
>>> x = 1.0/10
>>> y = 999.50/9
>>> x, y
(0.1, 111.05555555555556)
>>> x = x + y
>>> x
111.15555555555555
>>> y = x - y
>>> y
0.09999999999999432
>>> x = x -y
>>> x,y
(111.05555555555556, 0.09999999999999432)
```